# XUnit compatibility with .NET 4.6/UWP 10 PCL

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, portable-class-library, xunit, .net-4.6

I can't install xUnit in my Portable Class Library, which targets .NET Framework 4.6, ASP.NET Core, and UWP 10.

My project.json looks like this:

```
{
  "supports": {
    "net46.app": {},
    "uwp.10.0.app": {}
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.1.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    ".NETStandard1.3": {}
  }
}
```

When I try to install xUnit 2.1.0 using Nuget, the output is:

```
Restoring packages for C:\<redacted>\project.json...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/runtime.win8-arm.microsoft.netcore.runtime.coreclr/index.json
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/FindPackagesById()?id='runtime.win8-arm.Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR'
  OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/FindPackagesById()?id='runtime.win8-arm.Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR' 1147ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/runtime.win8-arm.microsoft.netcore.runtime.coreclr/index.json 1374ms
xunit.assert 2.1.0 is not compatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.3.
Some packages are not compatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.3.
```

Why is this happening? Is there anything I can do about it at my end, or would something need to change in xUnit?

An aside: when I tick the box to add ASP.NET Core 1.0 to my PCL's target list, Visual Studio processes for a moment, but doesn't actually change the project.json at all. When I go back into the PCL's project properties and inspect the list of targets, ASP.NET Core 1.0 is once again unticked. I'm not sure if this is a bug, or even whether it's related to the above issue?

Comment: which `Portable Class Library` are you creating? The `Class Library (Universal Windows)` or `Class Library (.Net Core)`?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I don't understand your question. I ticked both Universal Windows 10.0 and ASP.NET Core 1.0 on the target list for the PCL. Doesn't that mean my PCL is targeting both? You seem to be suggesting that I need to pick one or the other.